# Redshift Vacuum No Impact

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, vacuum

I have a few large tables (~1/2bn rows) on AWS Redshift. These tables have a small pct_unsorted as they're Vacuum'ed every weekend. The pct_unsorted climbs by 0.5% everyday due to new records. I use **SVV_TABLES** and **SVV_TABLE_INFO** to find out the pct_unsorted and vacuum_sort_benefit.

Recently, I have noticed that when I run the Vacuum on these tables on the weekend it seems to have no impact on the pct_unsorted. Is this possible? Is it that the SVV_TABLES and SVV_TABLE_INFO are inaccurate? or is my Vacuum not doing anything?

Comment: Can you paste your exact, actual `VACUUM` command, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Vacuum only sorts a table when the percent unsorted is greater than 5%.  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_VACUUM_command.html

> "By default, VACUUM skips the sort phase for any table where more than
> 95 percent of the table's rows are already sorted. Skipping the sort
> phase can significantly improve VACUUM performance. To change the
> default sort or delete threshold for a single table, include the table
> name and the TO threshold PERCENT parameter when you run VACUUM."

So unless you are changing the "threshold" of the VACUUM command or the percent unsorted is > 5% the command is not sorting your table.

Comment: Thank you very much Bill Weiner this was exactly my issue, you've cleared that up for me.